# Does the @synchronized on the NSMutableArray also take the synchronized effects on its element?

Tags: ios, nsarray

If a NSMutableArray is synchronized by the @synchronized, What about the elements in the array? are they also synchronized?

For example, I lock the array by the @synchronized (array) to get an element in that array, Can I ensure that the element I've got won't be changed (like changes on the value of some properties of the element) by other thread during my access of it?

Or besides locking the array, I have to lock the element again to prevent others to change the properties of the element?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It'd be a lot better to think that locking is the means of protecting code executions, not protecting shared data.

@synchronized (mutable array) {} block doesn't protect any data, it just ensure the same block is not executed simultaneously by multiple threads. Putting a mutable array object inside of parenthesis usually denote 'scope of lock'. That is, saying "this lock object is only associated with this object".

So, most easiest and safest way to using @synchronized is `@synchronized (self)`. And in this case, it is telling clearly, "this class is only accessed by a single thread at a time".

> If a NSMutableArray is synchronized by the @synchronized, What about the elements in the array? are they also synchronized?

A: NO

Answer (score 0):

No, it will only affect top-level dictionary access, provided all other code paths follow the same convention of locking the array.

In order to again exclusive access to an element in the array, you'll need to lock it explicitly, and again, all other code paths need to follow this protocol.